# avoid exiting yasnippet with escape while in evil mode's insert state

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, yasnippet

Is it possible to change yasnippet so it won't exit on escape during evil mode's insert state? I would like to be able to manipulate the text while still editing the snippet.

Thanks!